# Best Practice - API successful response message

Tags: rest, api

My current project API using this response on success:

1. if it's create -> it will send created object (201)
2. if it's update -> it will send updated object (200)
3. if it's delete -> it will send 204 response

Most of recommendation for example http://jsonapi.org/ never said about successful message to shown to user. I've followed their rules to keep returning object or 204 on success

What if I want to show to user alert "Successfully created" or "Successfully updated"?. Should the message come directly from server or client side (type it down or use some locales)?

Comment: Invaluable resource:  http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html

Answer (score 2):

You should review the RFC 7231, and it's description of [200 OK](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1)

> The payload sent in a 200 response depends on the request method. For the methods defined by this specification, the intended meaning of the payload can be summarized as:
>
> POST  a representation of the status of, or results obtained from, the action;
> PUT, DELETE  a representation of the status of the action;

So yes, using the response body to present a representation of an alert to the user is *fine*.

For [201 Created](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.2), the same basic rule applies

> The 201 response payload typically describes and links to the resource(s) created.

[204 No Content](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5) is not similar, for the simple reason that "No Content" refers to the message body; `204` is one of the ways that you can indicate to the client (and intermediary components) that the 0 byte payload is not an error.

> The 204 response allows a server to indicate that the action has been successfully applied to the target resource, while implying that the user agent does not need to traverse away from its current "document view" (if any).  The server assumes that the user agent will provide some indication of the success to its user, in accord with its own interface, and apply any new or updated metadata in the response to its active representation.